# Trying to play sound during an animation, however the sound is played once for every frame of the animation

Tags: android, animation, audio, libgdx

As the title suggests, I am trying to run a sound bite when a certain animation plays, I am having no issues with the other sounds and by using deduction I have concluded that the sounds are looping every time a frame of the animation passes. It is supposed to be that the shark collides with a mine, the mine explodes, a boom is heard and the game ends.

Edit: The code for the Boom Sound is only called when the collision is detected. There is another sound for when the player collides with collectibles, but that
sound works fine. It's only when the player collides with the mine and it plays the explosion animation does the sound messes up. It is restarting every time a frame of the animation passes.

```
 if (Intersector.overlaps(this.mineC[i], this.sharkC)) {
            this.boomsound.play();
            this.collision = true;
            this.gamestate = 2;
            this.runtime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            this.game.batch.draw((TextureRegion) this.boom.getKeyFrame(this.runtime, false), (float) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 5), this.sharkY - 120.0f);

            this.boom.setPlayMode(PlayMode.NORMAL);
            if (this.boom.isAnimationFinished(this.runtime)) {
                boomsound.stop();
                this.game.setScreen(new GameOverShark(this.game));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.boomsound.play()` called in every iteration in your code, you should call it only once

```
 // field
 private boolean boomNotStarted = true; 

 ....

 if (Intersector.overlaps(this.mineC[i], this.sharkC)) {
      if (boomNotStarted) {
            this.boomsound.play();
            this.boomNotStarted = false;
      }

      ...
 }
```

Comment: How exactly would I implement this code? NotStarted doesn't seem to be a thing within libgdx and I'm not the best with code.

Comment: It was a pseudo code to give you a general idea about what went wrong. I edited code and made it executable. It's pretty horrible implementation, but I can't give you more because I don't know much about your program. Edited code won't work if you need more than one boom events, and it can have even more problems

Comment: I see now, sorry I was having issues visualizing the code. but I placed your edited code into my program and It works now. Many thanks to you